# Touchscreen in CE5 blocking data traffic from peripheral

Tags: c#, windows-ce, touchscreen

We are developing a platform with Windows CE 5 (soon to be upgraded to 6) in .Net CF 2 C#.

What we have recently discovered is that if we are touching the touchscreen while using our peripheral, the peripheral data trafic times out and our application crashes. So it seems like the touchscreen is blocking it. As a quick fix we would like to disable the touchscreen while using the peripheral, and the reenabling it.

So our question is, how do we do it?

Do we need some extra packages in the OS build or can we do it manually. We have had a look at touchpaneldisable() and touchpanelenable(...). But the enable method requires a handle to the callback function. So I have no idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

From an application perspective tehre really isn't a fix.  Touchpanel ddrivers a re alittle different than otehrs becasue they get loaded by (and into) GWES, rather than device.exe.  They are not designed to be disabled and enabled, though some OEMs do provide the capability (typically by just masking the touch panel interrupt).

It sounds like the touchpanel sampling rate is really high and the device is saturating the processor when it startes sampling.  It's something that the OEM probably needs to fix.  Some OEMs do provide registry entries to adjust the driver behavior, so check with them to see if this might be available to you.  In that case you may be able to fix the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the BSP you might want to go through [this blog post](http://discovertheexperience.blogspot.com/2009/12/windows-embedded-ce-touch-driver.html) as it suggest possible bottle necks for the touch driver.